# Android: How to eliminate spoken text from AccessibilityEvents when extending SeekBar?

Tags: android, accessibility, seekbar, talkback

My Android app contains a custom slider control based on the `SeekBar`, and I want to attach a custom text phrase to my control to explain its use for Accessibility.

I have done this successfully using `View.setContentDescription(text)`, and TalkBack correctly speaks the phrase when I request focus on my slider control from `Activity.onCreate`.

So far, so good. However, when I touch the control, which I believe sets the AccessibilityFocus on my Android API 16 test device, extra words are being added to the spoken phrase, i.e. '...seek control. 0 per cent'. I want to remove these additional words.

I have tried to eliminate them using `event.getText().clear()` in `View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event)` without success. Echoing the event to LogCat reports the correct phrase in `event.contentDescription` and no entries in `event.text`, but the extra words appear both in the audio output from the device hardware and in the on-screen debug text displayed by *Menu->Settings->Accessibility->TalkBack->Settings->Developer Settings->Display Speech Output*.

Please can anyone suggest where the extra words are being added, and how to eliminate them?

Any constructive suggestions would be welcomed. Thanks.

**Update**

I can see that some Explore By Touch (initial single-tap) event on my custom control does not pass through either its `onInitializeAccessibilityEvent` or `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` methods as I am deliberately calling `event.setContentDescription(null)`. Despite this, there is an `AccessibilityEvent` being generated with my custom control's `ContentDescription`, set in `Activity.onCreate` in code, plus the extra words I'm trying to eliminate.

I've also set an `AccessibilityDelegate` on my custom control's parent `ViewGroup` to give visibility of its `onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent` calls. This confirms that no event containing my `ContentDescription` is passing through.

This is very puzzling, and happens on both the emulator and real hardware with API 16. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug in TalkBack, and have raised [Google Eyes-Free issue #375](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/detail?id=375), including example code.

**Update:** Google have now archived this. Link moved to: http://code.google.com/archive/p/eyes-free/issues/375

Comment: Link is now dead.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to override http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)

and set the contentDescription there.

If you want to remove the 0%, I would try to change the class in AccessibilityNodeInfo/AccessibilityEvent:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#setClassName(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Changing the class will prevent the user to set its values by using the volume keys

Comment: @DiegoMalone Check my answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740141/how-to-prevent-android-talkback-to-speak-seekbar-progress/64703579#64703579