# Can't change default SeekBar TalkBack from Custom View

Tags: android, accessibility, seekbar, talkback

Currently, when the SeekBar is selected it says `"%d percent, <content description>, Seek Control"` and then `"Use volume keys to adjust..."`, which is the default TalkBack for this SeekBar, but in my case, this is useless information, since the SeekBar moves in steps, for example, it can slide to option A, or option B or option C.

What I want is when the SeekBar is selected, TalkBar should read the content description only, or even better, just remove the `"%d percent"`.

I'm trying to modify the default TalkBack in a custom SeekBar Inheriting from `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar` but nothing that I've tried worked.

I've tried:

- reading the accessibility documentation for custom views but changing the event text did nothing: [Make custom views more accessible](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views).
  I tried to change the `event.text.add("custom text")` in all possible API methods. Also tried to use `event.clear()` before adding new text and to change the `event.beforeText`. Nothing worked
- this solution, but when I select the SeekBar it reads nothing. I'm guessing is because we are ignoring the TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64703579/10173087.
  This was a close one but didn't work because when the SeekBar is selected I need it to read something.
- this solution, but I don't think there is an action to modify the SeekBar label, as we have here on the button: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496367

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi @sam_k, sorry, I was not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be 100% relevant because this is the solution for a compose component, but you can remove the percent readout by changing the stateDescription

```
modifier = Modifier
            .semantics {
                stateDescription = [your state]
            }
```